# Is it possible for a Concurrent queue to perform 120 billions requests (enq/deql per second on rtx 4090

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, queue, hpc, gnu-parallel

I am currently working on concurrent queue. Whenever I ran Broker queue from their source code it shows it could execute 120 billions requests per seconds. This number looks so unbelievable to me.

I found their source code from the broker queue paper.

Comment: That does seem unrealistic. On a new M3 Max 14core, I can do 2.3 billion reads per second on a concurrent hash map, where the data fits in the cpu cache and a zipfian (skewed) distribution. A write path on a FIFO (hotspots), even if striped or other tricks, wouldn't reach that. Usually those fudge numbers are an accumulation across a cluster of machines (of unspecified count), so meaningless.